# Animating live changes in meteor issue

Tags: javascript, meteor, meteor-helper

I am trying to animate each time the post.text is updated in meteor using [Percolate:Momentum](https://atmospherejs.com/percolate/momentum) (I have tried other plugins but those didn't work either). The post.text updates fine, but it does not animate - not sure what I am doing wrong :S

JS

```
Template.textDisplay.helpers({
  post: function () {
    return MongoDatabase.findOne({}, { sort: { date: -1} });
  }
});

MongoDatabase.insert({
  text: message,
  date: new Date()
});
```

HTML

```
<template name="textDisplay">   
{{#momentum plugin='right-to-left'}}

    {{post.text}}

{{/momentum}}   
</template>
```

Comment: can you create `meteorpad` demo?

Comment: @MarkUretsky This is a short example of what I'm trying to animate  [link](http://meteorpad.com/pad/jL5sWmzRtd4ANZQuq/Test)

Comment: @MarkUretsky I have also tried changing the helper to show limit of 1 and:

{{#each post}}
    {{#momentum plugin='fade'}}      
      {{text}}      
    {{/momentum}}
{{/each}}

Still nothing :(

Comment: just answered, Unfortunately it's not you using it incorrectly it's possibly even not supported...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Peter looking at the code it seems like `Percolate:Momentum` support just multiple elements a `collection.find()` cursor with at least 2 elements works fine. I made a simple jQuery use of `fadeIn()` to show you how you can actually use any jQuery to animate it
http://meteorpad.com/pad/32rHhkm6NmdxSsTt4/Copy%20of%20Test

you can try open a github issue for `Percolate:Momentum` maybe they have a work around or find a different library? But if it's just a single element it's actually easy to use jQuery for this. But there probably should be different animation package that works with just one element. Hopefully this is helpful.